# How to maintain component state after page rerender/change?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, state

I have a counter made using context API and I need it to maintain the current state after the page is changed. Is there any way to keep the *Counter* value on page change like in session storage or something? I'm using react router to change the pages.

```
export const CounterContext = React.createContext()



function App() {

  const [Counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    setCounter(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('count')));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('count', Counter);
  }, [Counter]);
  
  function ChangeCounter() {
    setCounter(Counter+1);
  }
  console.log(Counter);

  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={{Counter, ChangeCounter}}>
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Navbar />
      </header>
      <div className="Content">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/Products">
            <Products />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/Contact">
            <Contact />
          </Route>        
        
        </Switch>
      </div>
      
      <footer>
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </div>
    </Router>
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Edit:
I made it using local storage but I'm not really sure is that what I wanted. Now even on browser restart the counter stay on the same updated value but I want it to refresh. Is there a way to do that now?

Comment: I'm not familiar with redux or react's router but what about browser's `localstorage` ?

Comment: The state should be preserved when you visit different page routes. The only reason it wouldn't is if `App` is being remounted. Could you show the code which renders `App`, and maybe your code for changing page as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I made it. Thanks a lot everyone! I used the sessionStorage to stor the data only during the session. It looks like this:

```
export const CounterContext = React.createContext()



function App() {

  const [Counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    setCounter(JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('count')));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('count', Counter);
  }, [Counter]);

  function ChangeCounter() {
    setCounter(Counter+1);
  }
  console.log(Counter);
//and the rest  of the code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies for this functionality.
You can prefer [universal-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie) to manipulate cookies in react

```
npm install universal-cookie
```